# Ionic back button hasn't the same behaviour as firing $ionicHistory.goBack() manually

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

When I try to navigate from

`main.admin` to `main.admin.emergencyDetail` to `main.admin.emergencyDetail.photos`

back with the normal back button in the upper left corner, then I get to

`main.admin`

but when I use on the `main.admin.emergencyDetail.photos` state something like:

```
$timeout(function () {
  $ionicHistory.goBack();
}, 5000)
```

Then I get as you would expect to `main.admin.emergencyDetail` (Which I want in the end). Where is the problem here?

app.js:

```
      $stateProvider
  // this state is placed in the <ion-nav-view> in the index.html
    .state('main', {
      url: '/main',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'main/templates/menu.html',
      controller: 'MenuCtrl as menu'
    })
    .state('main.inactive', {
      url: '/inactive',
      views: {
        'pageContent': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/inactive.html',
          controller: 'InactiveCtrl as inactive'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.profile', {
      url: '/profile',
      views: {
        'pageContent': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/profile.html',
          controller: 'ProfileCtrl as profile'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.active', {
      url: '/active',
      views: {
        'pageContent': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/active.html',
          controller: 'ActiveCtrl as active'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      views: {
        'pageContent': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/admin.html',
          controller: 'AdminCtrl as admin'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.admin.settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      views: {
        'pageContent@main': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/admin-settings.html',
          controller: 'AdminSettingsCtrl as adminsettings'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.admin.registration', {
      url: '/registration',
      views: {
        'pageContent@main': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/admin-registration.html',
          controller: 'AdminRegistrationCtrl as adminregistration'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.admin.activePupils', {
      url: '/active/pupils',
      views: {
        'pageContent@main': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/pupils-active.html',
          controller: 'PupilsActiveCtrl as pupilsactive'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.admin.activeAdmins', {
      url: '/active/admins',
      views: {
        'pageContent@main': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/admin-active.html',
          controller: 'AdminActiveCtrl as adminactive'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.admin.emergencyDetail', {
      url: '/emergency/:id',
      views: {
        'pageContent@main': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/admin-emergency-detail.html',
          controller: 'AdminEmergencyCtrl as adminemergency'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('main.admin.emergencyDetail.photos', {
      url: '/photos',
      views: {
        'pageContent@main': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/admin-emergency-photos.html',
          controller: 'AdminEmergencyCtrl as adminemergency'
        }
      }
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/inactive');
```

I use the same Controller for two views (written up there but might be important).

And here a screenshot of a log in the photos state:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after long recherching I found out that the following provider in .config helped: `$mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();`

This solved multiple issues (aswell $ionicPopup firing twice).